# Run VMware Player image as service Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, services, vmware-player

I have an image that I would like to run as service (running with VMware Player) in Windows 7.

The reason I want it as service so image will start running when server is going up, without forcing to do a user sign-in. What I did now was to put a shortcut of the .VMX on startup and then to sign-in with the user.

Comment: Same question asked on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/70887/vmware-player-running-as-a-service)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible using this very old free microsoft wrapper (google for explanations about srvany): ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/bussys/winnt/winnt-public/reskit/nt40/i386/srvany_x86.exe

Or there are also commercial tools: http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Apps/RunVMwarePlayerAsAService.html

Or you can try switching to [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org), which can run in the background just from the command line.

Comment: VirtualBox rules. This is old question.. i moved to VirtualBox since it has better support in advanced configuration as a free tool.

Answer (score 2):

Because VMWare VMPlayer requires a window to run in, and doesn't support running windowless, there is no way you can achieve this, with this free product.

If you are able to purchase a copy of VMWare Workstation, then you could use a 'vmrun' command as a scheduled event for Windows startup (I do this myself).

Alternatively, and I have done this in the past, you could use VMWare Server (now unsupported) if your guest OS is compatible with that.